# Probability that no two teams in a tournament win the same number of games

Tags: probability

> Six teams play a tournament in which every team plays every other team exactly once. No ties occur, and each team has a $\dfrac{1}{2}$ probability of winning any game it plays. Find the probability that no two teams win the same number of games.

This is what I have so far:

There are $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ pairs of teams, and $2^{15}$ possible outcomes. The min and max possible # of games won are from $0$ to $5$. If $h$ represents the # of games on by a certain team, than $0 \leq k \leq 5$. Because of this, there are $5!$ outcomes in which no two teams win the same number of games. Therefore, the probability is: $\dfrac{5!}{2^{15}}$. When simplified, we get $\dfrac{15}{4096}$. However, when I imputed this answer into the question, it was wrong. Where was my error, and how can I fix it?

NOTICE: The probability of a team winning in each game is 1/2 , NOT 1/12.

Comment: Maybe there are 6! outcomes in which no two teams win the same number of games (order the six teams best to worst and have the higher ranked team beat the lower ranked team in each game), so you'd get 6!/2^15 which would 6 times your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The total number of games won  must add up to $15$, since there were $15$ games. Each team must have won between $0$ and $5$ games. It's fairly obvious that the only way for none of the teams to have the same number of wins as another is if the six teams won $0,1,2,3,4$, and $5$ games.

I think this is where you made the innocent mistake. There are $6$ numbers to be distributed among the $6$ teams, which can be done in $6!=720$ different ways (not $5!=120$). The answer you seek is $\frac{720}{2^{15}}=\frac{45}{2048}$.

Comment: You may need an extra step, saying that if you know which teams won $0,1,2,3,4,5$ games then you know the result of each game (one team won all its games, another won all its other games, etc.)